# How can I optimize this code snippet to execute faster and with a smaller footprint?

Tags: php, memcached

We have a small script that uses memcache to track concurrent sessions, with the client making a new request every 10-seconds to "renew" its session and also get the latest count of users online.

```
$session    = $_GET['session'];
$streamid   = $_GET['streamid'];

if(!is_null($session) && !is_null($streamid)) {
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

    $data   = $memcache->get($streamid);

    if($data === false) {
        $data   = array($session => time()+10);

        $memcache->add($streamid,$data,0,10);
    } else {
        $now            = time();
        $streamCount    = count($data);

        for($i=0;$i<$streamCount;$i++) {
            if($data[$i] > $now) {    
                    unset($data[$i]);
            }
        }

        $data[$session] = time()+10;
    }

    echo count($data);
} else {
    echo 'no session or stream specified';
}
```

Comment: You don't really ask a question here. Your title says you want help optimising the snippet, but the question itself just dumps code on us. What, precisely, do you want to do? What have you tried so far? What are your ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I had to submit it several times to get the formatting right...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is minimize the amount of time to execute this code. I suppose the for loop is the most intensive thing here. Anyone have any ideas on how I can remove having to loop through all items in the array to see which have expired?

Comment: Have you profiled it? What section is taking the longest amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running this yet? Do you need to optimize it? Maybe it works like how you want it right now. It seems like a better solution would be to decouple it and write it as clean as possible. Put timers around calls and if you see something being slow then try to fix that code. Don't optimize if you don't need to.